# A word for "bringing something to its required amount"

Tags: single-word-requests

Stewart paid a security deposit for his apartment rental. The deposit needs to be for three months of rent.
In the first year, he paid $1000 a month, so his deposit was $3000.

In his third year, the rent had been raised to $1,200 a month, and the landlord realized that the deposit was not sufficient, as there is a gap of $600 between 3 months of rent and the deposit he currently has.

Now he needs to collect another $600 from Stewart.

What is the correct word for this action of closing the gap betweent he two amounts? I need a term as technical as possible.

Example sentence, but you can be flexible.

> The landlord decided to ____________ the deposit.

Comment: If he raises the rent, doesn't he also *raise* the deposit?

Comment: We need more context. Did the landlord *supplement* the deposit? Did he *catch up* or *top off* the deposit by charging an addtional $50 per month for one year? **Who** brought it up to its required amount? **How** was this done?

Comment: The technical term is _tweak_. Technical, but informal.

Comment: "re-calibrate" would also be a very technical way of making such type of adjustment --- I don't think it would apply to a rental deposit though.

Comment: "update" I think would get the point across best

Comment: To me **adjust** seems natural. In many circumstances I'd use 'top-up' but normally that  would be the action of the person who makes the additional payment.

Comment: *adjust*    .......

Comment: Requisition or solicit are a close fit. "The landlord decided to requisition/solicit the remaining funds." I realize this isn't exactly what you're looking for since it forces a change in the object of the sentence (from "the deposit" to "the remaining funds"). But if you can't find your desired word, this might work.

Comment: Informally, the landlord decided he needed to ***up*** the deposit.

Comment: "Charge a supplemental deposit " would describe what the landlord did. He hasn't really raised the deposit, he's asking for it to be augmented by a one-off payment or supplemental charge. You could also say that he has asked for the deposit to be _augmented_ since he still holds the initial deposit; you can't really say that _he_ has augmented the deposit because Stewart will do that when he gives him the 600 bucks.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of terms, but each would have the renter, not the landlord as the agent.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/top-up

1. **Top-up**

This is mostly British usage. From [the OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/top-up)

> *Noun*, British
>
> And additional or extra amount or payment that restores something to
>   the level that is required.
>
> “They will miss out on hundreds of pounds worth of pension top-ups”

2. **True-up**

Informal, this is from the [urban dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm=true-up&amp=true), not an actual dictionary.

> To correct any skewed perception or actuality
>
> Uses: true-up, truing-up, trued-up, true up, truing up, trued up A
>   large company buys X number licenses of software program for use by
>   the employees. As the company grows the software program gets copied
>   and used, therefore cheating the software makers out of money. Yearly,
>   the company needs to "true-up" the copies being used and pay the
>   software makers for what they are actually using.

This term is more commonly used by car and bicycle mechanics, but it can be used for money too.

Ps: I don’t know this for sure, but my guess is that this informal use (in quotes) in the context of money comes from the actual use of the term “true up” in accounting, with the meaning “to make an entry to reconcile a calculation”.

Since you need the landlord to be the one making the decision, could you perhaps frame your sentence as “**The landlord decided to make him top up the deposit**.”?

Answer (score 0):

"The landlord decided to **revise** the security deposit fee."

Comment: At SE we're looking for answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.